# Why Does this Macro Keep Deleting ALL of the Data

Tags: excel, vba

I have this Macro that copies one sheet from another Workbook that i open via a File Dialog. It is supposed to sort and delete the Rows whose A Column does not possess data in an Array I've defined. It appears to be copying and pasting the data properly but when it runs through the loop to delete the data that doesn't contain the items in the array it ends up clearing the entire sheet

This Macro worked last Friday when I left for the day but now it seems it no longer works. I've tried stepping through the code but the loop doesn't appear to change much so I'm unsure why it stopped working over the weekend.

```
Public filepath As String

Sub SPOMacro()

'Display a Dialog Box that allows to select a single file.
'The path for the file picked will be stored in fullpath variable
  With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        'Makes sure the user can select only one file
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        'Filter to just the following types of files to narrow down selection options
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xls; *.xlsb", 1
        'Show the dialog box
        .Show

        'Store in fullpath variable
        fullPath = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
    End With
    filepath = fullPath
    'It's a good idea to still check if the file type selected is accurate.
    'Quit the procedure if the user didn't select the type of file we need.
    If InStr(fullPath, ".xls") = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Open the file selected by the user
    'Workbooks.Open fullpath

    'This is the Copy Sheet Portion
    'MsgBox filepath

    Dim spo_book As Workbook
    Dim target_book As Workbook
    Set spo_book = Workbooks("SPO_Untimed_Report.xlsm")
    Set target_book = Workbooks.Open(filepath)

    Dim dst_sheet As Worksheet
    Dim target_sheet As Worksheet
    Set dst_sheet = spo_book.Sheets("SPO Data")
    Set target_sheet = target_book.Sheets("Untimed Parts")
    dst_sheet.Cells.Clear
    dst_sheet.Cells.Delete
    Z = Cells(Sheets("Untimed Parts").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    target_sheet.Range("A1:R" & Z).Copy
    dst_sheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial

    ' Sort Pasted Data by Cost Ctr
    Dim dontDelete
    dontDelete = Array("RX01225", "RX01303", "RX01304", "RX01314", "RX01338", "Cost Ctr")

    dst_sheet.Activate

    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Dim isThere As Boolean

    For i = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        For j = LBound(dontDelete) To UBound(dontDelete)
            If StrComp(Range("A" & i), dontDelete(j), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                isThere = True
            End If
        Next j
        If Not isThere Then
            Range("A" & i).Delete shift:=xlUp
        End If
        isThere = False
    Next i

    'Deletes Blank Rows
    Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete


End Sub
```

The expected outcome is that the workbook that I called SPO Untimed will keep the sheet called SPO Data and the data that is pasted into that sheet from the Selected Workbook (By the File Dialog) is sorted by the Array I've defined and only the rows that have those items in the A Column remain.

Comment: It could do with some minor improvements, but generally looks fine... If you don't have any of the values from your array, you will delete everything, so question is... are there any of the values from the array in the sheet `dst_sheet` (specifically in column `A`)?

Comment: I found the issue suddenly. It seems I had set a filter accidently in the workbook last friday when I was hand counting some of the data and I forgot to add in `Worksheet.ShowAllData` to ensure no Filters cause these errors.. I apologize